# Вывод Jquery переменных в span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вот примерный [аналог калькулятора](http://drawit.ru/example/kalkulyator-uslug-demo). Порядок такой я ввожу цифры в input мне выводятся сумма по формуле без кнопки.
Не могу понять почему не выводит в span значение переменной Jquery, в чем может быть проблема?

```js
function calculate() {
  var width = $('#width').val();
  var height = $('#height').val();
  var S = width * height;
  var total = width * height * 2500;
  var newTotal = Math.round(total);
  $('#fc_priceValue').html(newTotal);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Калькулятор</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="goup_param">
      <label>Ширина:
        <input type="text" class="form_price" name="width" id="width" value="" placeholder="0" />
      </label>
      <br />
      <br />
      <label>Высота:
        <input type="text" class="form_price" name="height" id="height" value="" placeholder="0" />
      </label>
      <br />
      <br />
      <label>Выбирите материал</label>
      <br />
      <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="total">
      <span id="fc_priceValue"></span> &#8381;
      <span id="fc_square" class="field">/ <span id="fc_squareValue">100</span>  <span id="fc_squareMeas">м</span><sup>2</sup>
      </span>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем коде есть сразу несколько проблем.

Во-первых, вы используете неправильный селектор для целевого `span`. Вместо `$('.fc_priceValue')` должно быть `$('#fc_priceValue')`.

Во-вторых, не похоже, что функция `calculate` хоть где-то вызывается. Можно, например, добавить маленькую кнопочку в форму, например так:

```
<button onclick="calculate()">Рассчитать</button>
```

При желании, можно обойтись без кнопки. Для современных браузеров, я бы предложил использовать событие [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/input) для пересчета конечного значения. Вот пример:

```
<input type="text" id="width" value="" oninput="calculate()" />
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/azavff56/1/) рабочего кода на JSFiddle.

---

**Для справки:**

Селекторы вида `.foo` выбирают элементы *по классу*, в то время как селекторы вида `#foo` выбирают элементы *по идентификатору*. Судя по приведенной разметке вам нужен именно второй вариант.

Comment: Я сделал как вы говорите, но результата ноль. Текст в span-е не отображается! Черт его знает почему возможно нужно использовать ready document или как то так, но точно не знаю как это должно выглядеть!

Comment: А вы уверены, что функцию `calculate` хоть кто-то вызывает?! У меня, например, все отлично работает https://jsfiddle.net/azavff56/

Comment: Да так понятно! Но как сделать без кнопки, чтобы калькулятор начал считать?
onclick="calculate()" это решение не подходит.

Comment: @ggLike, понятия не имею **что именно** вы хотите сделать. Думаю вам стоит немножко подумать и максимально четко  уточнить вопрос

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, подозреваю тут имеют ввиду  `onchange` на инпутах

Comment: @Grundy, возможно. Но без четкой формулировки этого момента **в вопросе**, ответ я править не стану. Если хотите -- можете дать свой ответ (или исправить мой) =)

Comment: http://drawit.ru/example/kalkulyator-uslug-demo/ Вот примерный аналог калькулятора. 
Порядок такой я ввожу цифры в input мне выводятся сумма по формуле без кнопки.

Comment: @ggLike, ссылки могут служить только **дополнением**. Все желаемое поведение стоит описать словами в самом вопросе.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev вопрос дополнен!

Comment: @ggLike, обновил ответ

Comment: Благодарю. Работает!!! @Dmitriy Simushev вы однозначно ответили на мой вопрос!